# Draw a square with grid in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I am trying to create my own geom. On screen, the geom should always be a square, irrespective of scaling. Given the values `w` and `h` (for width and height), transformed by ggplot from user coordinates to grid coordinates, the idea is to shrink one of them such that on screen, the aspect of the resulting rectangle is exactly w/h. If w==h, we get a square.

It is doable in basic R by consulting `par("pin")`:

```
## w and h are box width and height in user coordinates
## if w == h, we will should get a square
aspect <- 1 # change to get a rectangle with a given aspect ratio
pp <- par("pin")
pu <- par("usr")
pu <- c(pu[2]-pu[1], pu[4]-pu[3])
ppu <- pp/pu

wi <- w * ppu[1] # box width in inches
hi <- h * ppu[2] # box height in inches

if(wi > hi * aspect) {
  wi <- hi * aspect
} else {
  hi <- wi / aspect
}

w <- wi / ppu[1]
h <- hi / ppu[2]
```

However, I have hard time figuring out how to do the same with grid. Is it possible?

What I want to do: I want to make a little plot-in-plot which, in some cases, needs to be exactly a square otherwise it looks ugly.

Comment: There are other ways to make a plot-in-plot, for example with `grid::grid.newpage()` + `viewport()`. Might be easier

Comment: Yeah, or using coord_fixed() in ggplot. The more I think about it, the more it is like that it cannot be possible.